# Is there a word for the satisfaction of finding what you were looking for?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests

Basically, Title. Is there any word for that feeling when you finally find what you've been looking for? Be it a definition for a word, or your long lost brother, or some rare bird.

Edit: To clarify, not necessarily a new discovery, but perhaps something lost, or that you know is out there, you just didn't know where until you found it. I guess it would be some variant of 'satisfaction'

Comment: Sample sentence please!

Comment: Basically, yes, that's called "satisfaction"

Answer (score 0):

**eureka moment**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Eureka)

A moment or instance at which a sudden, revelatory idea, realization, or solution to a problem comes to mind. We'd been working on the problem in the lab for weeks, but the eureka moment came to me when I was out gardening!

Answer (score 0):

Eureka moment is good for the really big realizations.  For more everyday use:

**[Aha moment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aha%20moment)**

> a moment of sudden realization, inspiration, insight, recognition, or comprehension *The aha moment you experience when you've been trying to remember the name of a song and three hours later it hits you … —Jeffrey Kluger* (Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 0):

**Jubilation**

> a feeling of great happiness and triumph.

Jubilation: Google's dictionary - [jubilation](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+jubilation&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+jubilation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.7182j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)